# How to summarize contents of webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have written code to summarize text using NLP, and am trying to make a chrome extension which uses the code to summarize the contents of a page. How would I access the contents of the page (all of the relevant text)? Does the chrome extension API have something for this? I am very new to all of this, so I hope my question doesn't bother any of you.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject content scripts, the scripts have access to the page's DOM, can get all of the text.